# QPushButton with transparent background

Tags: python, pyqt, transparency, pyqt5, qpushbutton

How to do transparent background in QPushButton?

I have a background picture and I want to make the button transparent.

I tried to use:

```
reg_screen_var.new_account.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: #F6F6F6; background: transparent}")
```

and:

```
reg_screen_var.new_account.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

But I get this result:

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

full code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPixmap, QFont, QMouseEvent)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QEvent, pyqtSignal, QCoreApplication, QObject)
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root = QWidget()


class RegisterScreenVar():

    def __init__(self):

        self.drop_logo = QLabel(root)
        self.drop_png = QPixmap("images/DropMeLogo.png")
        self.login_but = QLabel(root)
        self.login_but_img = QPixmap("images/Login_but.png")
        self.login_lab = QLabel('Login', root)
        self.pas_lab = QLabel('Password', root)
        self.login_box = QLineEdit(root)
        self.reg_box = QLineEdit(root)
        self.new_account = QPushButton("Don't have an account?", root)


reg_screen_var = RegisterScreenVar()


def drop_me():

    def register_screen(reg_screen_var, root, app):
        # design of register screen

        root.resize(1280, 720)
        root.move(400, 200)
        root.setWindowTitle('Drop_Me')
        root.setStyleSheet('background-image: url(images/reg_back.png);')

        reg_screen_var.login_but.setPixmap(reg_screen_var.login_but_img)
        reg_screen_var.login_but.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        reg_screen_var.login_but.move(520, 500)

        reg_screen_var.drop_logo.setPixmap(reg_screen_var.drop_png)
        reg_screen_var.drop_logo.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        reg_screen_var.drop_logo.move(370, 0)

        reg_screen_var.login_lab.setFont(QFont("OpenSans-Regular", 20, QFont.Bold))
        reg_screen_var.login_lab.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: #F6F6F6}')
        reg_screen_var.login_lab.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        reg_screen_var.login_lab.move(580, 230)

        reg_screen_var.pas_lab.setFont(QFont("OpenSans-Regular", 20, QFont.Bold))
        reg_screen_var.pas_lab.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: #F6F6F6}')
        reg_screen_var.pas_lab.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        reg_screen_var.pas_lab.move(550, 350)

        reg_screen_var.login_box.setFont(QFont("OpenSans-Regular", 18, QFont.Bold))
        reg_screen_var.login_box.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit {color:black; width: 300px}')
        reg_screen_var.login_box.move(470, 290)

        reg_screen_var.reg_box.setFont(QFont("OpenSans-Regular", 18, QFont.Bold))
        reg_screen_var.reg_box.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit {color:black; width: 300px}')
        reg_screen_var.reg_box.move(470, 400)

        reg_screen_var.new_account.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: #F6F6F6}")
        reg_screen_var.new_account.setFont(QFont("OpenSans-Regular", 10, QFont.Bold))
        reg_screen_var.new_account.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        reg_screen_var.new_account.move(540, 620)


        root.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    register_screen(reg_screen_var, root, app)

drop_me()
```

Comment: This problem with OS?

Comment: The solution is probably not the same for all platforms. It might help if you also posted a simple test script that shows how you created the window shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Github.com/geneus003/DropMe

Comment: I'm commit actual code on github (https://github.com/Geneus003/DropMe/blob/master/DropMe.py)
or U can use full code in task 
Sorry for late

Comment: When I add the two lines at the top of your question to the script, it works fine for me on archlinux (using qt-5.10.0 and pyqt 5.9.2). What *specifc* versions of qt and pyqt are you using?

Comment: Im using PyQt 5.9.2 and Qt version 5.9.3

Comment: I suppose there might be a bug in qt5 that only affects ubuntu. If the transparency works using qt4 (or an earlier version of qt5), that might confirm the bug.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt Designer Linux (Debian, Ubuntu) transparent background gave me Black color ,
so  Stylesheet of Qpush Button settings:

```
border : 0;
background: transparent;
```

i´ve spent hours trying. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the style.

```py
app.setStyle('Fusion')
```

Gives the me the problem. Try using

```py
app.setStyle("Windows")
```

That should be able to fix the problem. But you won't be able to use the 'Fusion' style. I hadn't tested it with other styles yet. I hope that solves your problem.